# How to select cells based on specific string in a range?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to look for a string "GAS CYLINDERS" in range "B17:B29" and if a cell contains the given string, go to column "H"(from "B") of the same row of the cell which contains the string then, select it.I want it to loop till row 29 and keep on selecting the eligible cells and take the sum of the values of all selected cells and finally , paste the total in another cell ("M22")

Code I tried:

```
ROW_NUMBER = 16
ROW_NUMBER = ROW_NUMBER + 1
PARTICULARS = Sheets("Invoice").Range("B" & ROW_NUMBER)
XXX = InStr(PARTICULARS, "GAS CYLINDER")

For Each XXX In Range("B17: B29")
    If MYRNG = Empty And InStr(PARTICULARS, "GAS CYLINDER") > 1 Then
        MYRNG = XXX.Address
    ElseIf InStr(PARTICULARS, "GAS CYLINDER") > 1 Then
        MYRNG = MYRNG & "," & XXX.Address
    End If
Next XXX

Range(MYRNG).Select
Selection.Offset(0, 6).Select
```

Image for reference
[image: Image for reference]

PS: I'm new to VBA. The code that i tried i found on You tube and Google and I modified it a little because the code i initially found didn't get me the expected result.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel 20 seconds search on google with your question title. Please put some effort into it.

Comment: ROW_NUMBER = 16

ROW_NUMBER = ROW_NUMBER + 1
PARTICULARS = Sheets("Invoice").Range("B" & ROW_NUMBER)
'XXX = InStr(PARTICULARS, "GAS CYLINDER"

For Each XXX In Range("B17: B29")
If MYRNG = Empty And InStr(PARTICULARS, "GAS CYLINDER") > 1 Then
MYRNG = XXX.Address
ElseIf InStr(PARTICULARS, "GAS CYLINDER") > 1 Then
MYRNG = MYRNG & "," & XXX.Address
End If
Next XXX


Range(MYRNG).Select


Selection.Offset(0, 6).Select

Comment: Can you add the code into the original post, and tag with the code tags (`{}`)? It's hard to read in the comments.

Comment: I hate to be pedantic (but computer programs **are**, so you need to get used to it) but you say "I want to look for a string "GAS CYLINDERS" " and then you show sample data that does not contain that string anywhere.

Comment: @BruceWayne i hope the code i tried initially can be  clearly seen now.

Comment: @YowE3K text in cells "b17","b19",b21"(in the image) contain "GAS CYLINDERS" in them?

Comment: Programs won't match "GAS CYLINDERS" with "GAS CYLINDER" - there is no "S" on the end of the string in your sample data - that's why I say you need to get used to them being pedantic.  (It looks like your code is searching for the correct thing, so it is only the question that isn't pedantic enough.)

Comment: @YowE3K understood. thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there is very rarely a need to `Select` things in VBA.

You want to calculate a number and place that into a cell, so simplify your code to just do that:

```
Dim XXX As Range
Dim myTotal As Long

For Each XXX In Range("B17: B29")
    If InStr(XXX.Value, "GAS CYLINDER") > 0 Then
        myTotal = myTotal + XXX.Offset(0, 6).Value
    End If
Next XXX

Range("M22").Value = myTotal
```

---

Or you could just use Excel's `SumIf` function:

```
Range("M22").Value = Application.SumIf(Range("B17:B29", "*GAS CYLINDER*", Range("H17:H29"))
```

Comment: works like a charm. Also, i'll keep the "select" suggestion in mind. Thanks a Ton for your time! Cheers!

Comment: @Sw1tch - When you have a moment, you should check out [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) on how to avoid using `.Select`/`.Activate`.

Comment: @BruceWayne i sure will. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using code instead of a formula?

In cell M22:

```
=SUMIF(B17:B21, "*Gas Cylinder*", H17:H21)
```

To compare and display an error message,

```
=IF(SUMIF(B17:B21, "*Gas Cylinder*", H17:H21)<>N22, "ERROR: ...", "")
```

Or test for true in M22 in your VBA save code:

```
=SUMIF(B17:B21, "*Gas Cylinder*", H17:H21)<>N22
```

Comment: i actually want excel to pop an error message if the total of the eligible cells doesnt match the value of cell "n22" when i click "save" command button on my userform.That is why i need the vba code.

Comment: Updated answer - just use the formula and test the value of M22.

Comment: @Sw1tch Or just use an `If Range("N22").Value <> Application.SumIf(Range("B17:B21", "*Gas Cylinder*", Range("H17:H21")) Then` in VBA.

Comment: testing the value of m22 in vba code worked.Thank You so much for your help and time! I really appreciate it! Also sorry for the trouble. Cheers!(to everyone)